# why is dropdown not working in ejs file in node Project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have included both javascript and bootstrap in my .ejs file in a nodejs project. The bootstrap css works on buttons(example btn btn-primary works) but the dropdown is not working.
//my index.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home automation system</title>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="test text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
                <h1>Home Automation system</h1>
                <p>The first Home Automation system in Bhutan</p> 
            </div>
            <% include partials/navbar.ejs %>
            <br><br>
            <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown button
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

//app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var lightController = require('./controllers/lightController');

var app=express();

//set the template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//link static files
app.use(express.static('./public'));

//to fire the controller
lightController(app);

//listen on port
app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running ...');
```

i have included the js and css folder extracted from bootstrap 4.3(downloaded) and included in the public folder.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: I think that you must include jquery library in order to make `dropdown` work

Comment: jquery added or not? if not then added and try.!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but using Bootstrap's CDNs. For dropdown to work one should include at least the followings two JavaScript libraries (Bootstrap and jQuery) in your HTML page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Checkout [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) for more info.